# Observable.SelectMany in an exclusive rather than shared manner

Tags: c#, system.reactive, observable

I'd like an observable operator very similar to `xs.SelectMany(_ => ys)`, only differing in that for every new input value, the previous result of the continuation/selector function should be unsubscribed from, making an exclusive message bus rather than a shared.

In marbles:

```
xs      S----o-----o----o------>
             |     |    |
ys1          S-o-o-+o-o-+o----->
               | | |    |
ys2            | | S-oo-+--o--->
               | |   || |   
ys3            | |   || S---o-->
               | |   ||     |
result        So-o---oo-----o-->
```

Note that nothing is yielded from ys1 once the second value of xs produced ys2. result should then unsubscribe from ys1. I hope this made clear what I want: Some kind of multiplexing behavior. This would be useful for changing sources (e.g. focused controls in a GUI) firing events.

Is there anything like that? Can I compose known operators for that behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the Switch http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229197%28v=vs.103%29.aspx and if you read this section on Switch http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/12_CombiningSequences.html you will see it has the same marble.